# Is there any Geometrical name for the overlapping region of three circles (at least two should overlap)?

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

Is there any geometrical name for the region depicted in the attached picture?

Comment: It looks like the [triquetra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triquetra) symbol in celtic/norse mythology,